# How to retrieve a python.logging log record over a socket

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

As part of my tests, trying to check if the log was received at the socket.
So a thread sends the log and the main thread tries to retrieve at the socket.

Not able to convert the received data into a log record.
Tried `logging.makeLogRecord` as per [Python 2.7 docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.makeLogRecord). Also tried `pickle` / `cPickle`

```
import unittest
import socketLogger
import logging
import logging.handlers
#import cPickle as pickle

def test_StringReceivedIsSameAsStringSent():
    host = 'localhost'
    port = 9000
    stringSent = "hello world!" 
    stringReceived = None
    log_msg = None

    def sendLogToSocket(host,port, stringSent):
        logger = logging.getLogger('mylogger') # to log Led Observer output over a socket
        sh = logging.handlers.SocketHandler(host,port) # handler to write to socket
        logger.addHandler(sh)
        logger.critical(stringSent) 
        logger.removeHandler(sh)
        sh.close()

    import threading
    t = threading.Thread(target=sendLogToSocket, args=(host,port,stringSent)) # socket requires 2 different ports if on the same machine
    t.start() # send log in a thread

    import socket
    serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) #INET => IPv4, STREAM => TCP
    serversocket.bind((host,port)) # 'localhost' => implies only visible within the same machine
    serversocket.listen(1) # accept 1 connection only
    (clientsocket, address) = serversocket.accept()
    stringReceived = clientsocket.recv(1024)
    print 'socketlistener: string received: ', repr(stringReceived)
    #obj = pickle.loads(stringReceived)
    #print 'un pickling log: ', obj
    #log_msg = logging.makeLogRecord(obj)
    log_msg = logging.makeLogRecord(stringReceived)
    print 'socketlistener: converted to log: ', log_msg
    clientsocket.close()
    serversocket.close()

    t.join() # wait for the log thread to finish

    print 'string sent: ', repr(stringSent), ' received: ', repr(stringReceived
    self.assertEqual(stringSent, stringReceived)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   test_StringReceivedIsSameAsStringSent()
```

output

```
E:\> python testSocket.py
socketlistener: string received:  '\x00\x00\x01}}q\x01(U\x0frelativeCreatedq\x02 G@\x18\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x00U\x07processq\x03M\xb0IU\x04argsq\x04NU\x06moduleq \x05U\ntestSocketq\x06U\x08funcNameq\x07U\x0fsendLogToSocketq\x08U\x08exc_textq\ tNU\x04nameq\nU\x08myloggerq\x0bU\x06threadq\x0cM|"U\x07createdq\rGA\xd6a\x040\x b1x\xd5U\nthreadNameq\x0eU\x08Thread-1q\x0fU\x05msecsq\x10G@\x88(\x00\x01\x00\x0 0\x00U\x08filenameq\x11U\rtestSocket.pyq\x12U\x07levelnoq\x13K2U\x0bprocessNameq \x14U\x0bMainProcessq\x15U\x08pathnameq\x16h\x12U\x06linenoq\x17K\x12U\x03msgq\x 18U\x0chello world!q\x19U\x08exc_infoq\x1aNU\tlevelnameq\x1bU\x08CRITICALq\x1cu.
'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testSocket.py", line 47, in <module>
    test_StringReceivedIsSameAsStringSent()
  File "testSocket.py", line 36, in test_StringReceivedIsSameAsStringSent
    log_msg = logging.makeLogRecord(stringReceived)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda2\lib\logging\__init_ _.py", line 340, in makeLogRecord
    rv.__dict__.update(dict)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Comment: Please use `print repr(string_variable)` instead of just `print`

Comment: @ArindamRoychowdhury here you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry my bad! forgot to RTM !

Required to 1. unpack the size and the data, 2. unpickle the data using size and 3. makeLogRecord of the unpickled object (earlier missed step 1)

Thanks to code on python docs: [logging cookbook sample](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#sending-and-receiving-logging-events-across-a-network) and [network logging sample](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/network-logging.html)

Here's my code corrected (assuming we get the size and full message in one socket.receive call):

```
import unittest
import socketLogger
import logging
import logging.handlers
import pickle
#import cPickle as pickle

def test_StringReceivedIsSameAsStringSent():
    host = 'localhost'
    port = 9000
    stringSent = "hello world!" 
    stringReceived = None
    log_msg = None

    def sendLogToSocket(host,port, stringSent):
        logger = logging.getLogger('mylogger') # to log Led Observer output over a socket
        sh = logging.handlers.SocketHandler(host,port) # handler to write to socket
        logger.addHandler(sh)
        logger.critical(stringSent) 
        logger.removeHandler(sh)
        sh.close()

    import threading
    t = threading.Thread(target=sendLogToSocket, args=(host,port,stringSent)) # socket requires 2 different ports if on the same machine
    t.start() # send log in a thread

    import socket
    serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) #INET => IPv4, STREAM => TCP
    serversocket.bind((host,port)) # 'localhost' => implies only visible within the same machine
    serversocket.listen(1) # accept 1 connection only
    (clientsocket, address) = serversocket.accept()
    chunk = clientsocket.recv(1024)
    print 'socketlistener: data received: ', repr(chunk)
    import struct
    slen = struct.unpack(">L", chunk[:4])[0]
    obj = pickle.loads(chunk[4:])
    print 'un pickling log: ', repr(obj)
    stringReceived = logging.makeLogRecord(obj)
    #log_msg = logging.makeLogRecord(stringReceived)
    print 'socketlistener: converted to log: ', repr(stringReceived)
    clientsocket.close()
    serversocket.close()

    t.join() # wait for the log thread to finish

    print 'string sent: ', repr(stringSent), ' received: ', repr(stringReceived.getMessage())
    assert(stringSent == stringReceived.getMessage())

if __name__ == "__main__":
   test_StringReceivedIsSameAsStringSent()
```

output

```
E:\> python testSocket.py
socketlistener: data received:  '\x00\x00\x01}}q\x01(U\x0frelativeCreatedq\x02G@ !\xff\xe9\x00\x00\x00\x00U\x07processq\x03M@5U\x04argsq\x04NU\x06moduleq\x05U\nt estSocketq\x06U\x08funcNameq\x07U\x0fsendLogToSocketq\x08U\x08exc_textq\tNU\x04n ameq\nU\x08myloggerq\x0bU\x06threadq\x0cM\\JU\x07createdq\rGA\xd6a\x05\x87\xbfl\ x8bU\nthreadNameq\x0eU\x08Thread-1q\x0fU\x05msecsq\x10G@\x8e\xf7\xff\xdf\x00\x00 \x00U\x08filenameq\x11U\rtestSocket.pyq\x12U\x07levelnoq\x13K2U\x0bprocessNameq\ x14U\x0bMainProcessq\x15U\x08pathnameq\x16h\x12U\x06linenoq\x17K\x13U\x03msgq\x1 8U\x0chello world!q\x19U\x08exc_infoq\x1aNU\tlevelnameq\x1bU\x08CRITICALq\x1cu.'

un pickling log:  {'threadName': 'Thread-1', 'name': 'mylogger', 'thread': 19036 , 'relativeCreated': 8.999824523925781, 'process': 13632, 'args': None, 'module' : 'testSocket', 'funcName': 'sendLogToSocket', 'levelno': 50, 'processName': 'Ma inProcess', 'created': 1501828638.991, 'msecs': 990.9999370574951, 'msg': 'hello world!', 'exc_info': None, 'exc_text': None, 'pathname': 'testSocket.py', 'file name': 'testSocket.py', 'levelname': 'CRITICAL', 'lineno': 19}
socketlistener: converted to log:  <logging.LogRecord object at 0x000000000276F4
00>
string sent:  'hello world!'  received:  'hello world!'
```